# Dialogflow messenger showing centered text in chat window for some reason

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-cx

I've just deployed the dialogflow messenger plugin via HTML to a second test website. In the first website, the chat window rendered perfectly. The second website however (a Magento PHP site that I don't have much control over) the same dialogflow with the same settings, shows all the responses from the bot as centered?

[image]

Here's the same chatbot, with the same HTML code, on a different (test) website running on my local machine (a flask site)

[image]

I've checked the available Dialogflow CX documentation - https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger - and I can't see any settings that would affect the alignment of text.

Agent html / CSS

Inline CSS:

```
<style>
            df-messenger {
            --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: #ec008c;
            }
</style>
```

Javascript:

HTML

```
<df-messenger
  df-cx="true"
  location="australia-southeast1"
  chat-title="x"
  agent-id="x"
  chat-icon=xxxx/girl.png
  language-code="en"
></df-messenger>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML you’re using and the CSS you are applying to both pages?

Comment: I've updated my post with both (assuming you mean just in relation to the agent itself)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare all the Sources that the page uses in both websites and see it you are missing anything
(like this) : 
 
  [image: F12 in your browser] 
 
If its the same then :

- you have a non closed div that effects the chatting section .
- you changed something in the functions that setts the plugin .
- you are calling the same script multiple times so it appears on the
  resources but doesn't cause errors in the console .